# Angular Select not changing model property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select that is bound to some property.

```
<select ng-model="IsComplete" ng-change="ChangeMe()" ng-options="item.DataListText as item.DataListText for item in YesNoValues">
    <option value="">-- Select Value --</option>
</select>
```

this is all happening on a modal that i display - this select works on other views in my app..just not on this modal for some reason.

In my module this is where i set the value - so my select is being bound correctly - it is displaying "Yes" - but when i change it to "No" it stays as "Yes"

```
$scope.IsCompleted = "Yes";
```

Here is my changeme function - i just put this in so i could see the value.

```
$scope.ChangeMe = function () {
    alert($scope.IsComplete);
}
```

Ive copied this code from another part of our app that works - this one doesnt. all other bindings on our modal are working. so i have some date inputs and when i change those it does change the scope and saves correctly. It is just this one dropdown.

Thanks in advance.

--Edit

Im getting closer to solving this - question if anyone knows - is ng-change called before ng-model is updated/changed.

I added an `<input ng-model="IsComplete" />` and when i change the dropdown my alert still says "Yes" but my input does say "No" - so im thinking my scope is being changed and Im just getting bogged down with what my alert says.

Comment: Best to add a jsFiddle here.. It will be easier for us to find a problem that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue - was tough to figure out. What was happening is that when i loaded the page (its a modal) i had this new scope. that was binding it and setting it to "No" - when i changed it a nested scope off that scope added the same property and that is where my changes were. my markup was referencing the parent scope and that was never changing - the nested scope was. so in my markup i added the object I had at load ("Person"). so instead of ng-model="IsCompleted" i put in ng-model="Person.IsCompleted" and this solved my issue. –

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try a [`$watch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) or use [`$scope.apply`](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)

Comment: I have not used $watch or apply - can you look at my response/solution above and let me know what is a better solution. thanks